# Why can't I change the speed of a CSS animation by adding a class?

Tags: css, css-animations

I defined an animation like this:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes pan {
    from {left: 10%;}
    to {left: 20%;}

}

#dot {
    background: black;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: pan 10s linear infinite;
}

body.fast > #dot {
    -webkit-animation: pan 1s linear infinite;
}
```

When I use JavaScript like this to change `#dot`'s class:

```js
document.body.classList.add('fast');
```

Nothing happens! What's up here?

Example: http://jsbin.com/buqowizi/2

Comment: when i click on the fast radio button no class is applied to the body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [specification for css animations](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-animations/#animation) states:

> Once an animation has started it continues until it ends or the animation-name is removed

As such with an animation time of "infinite" it can't be modified once started without modifying the animation-name.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AD7six/aLGGG/) demonstrating a change in speed (though it's not smooth, there's probably a more appropriate solution) the premis being:

```
div.reset {
    -webkit-animation: none; # <-
}
div.slow {
    -webkit-animation: pan 10s linear infinite;
}
div.fast {
    -webkit-animation: pan 1s linear infinite;
}
```

Change the class of the element so that the animation resets, and then start a new animation with a different duration.

Comment: @JimmyRare I see no difference clicking slow or fast on your jsbin demo link (debian chrome Version 34.0.1847.116).

Comment: How odd, I'm doing it right now in chrome.
Version 31.0.1650.63 m

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to specify the duration only:

```
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
```

And this javascript code should work:

```
var dot = document.getElementById('dot');
var fast = false;

speed.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  if(!fast) {
      dot.classList.add('fast');
      fast = !fast;
  } else {
      dot.classList.remove('fast');
      fast = !fast;
  }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/buqowizi/3/edit)

Answer (score 0):

here's a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/buqowizi/6/edit?html,css,js,output

i modified css, html and javascript to make it work.
your code was a bit buggy

Comment: forget about ie6 to ie9 it just doesn't support css animation, you will have to give it up or use a javascript fallback to animate your elements (which is a pain).. about chrome, yes sorry, i didn't notice, im gonna look it up now